# Determining if the sequence $\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}$ is monotonic and bounded

Tags: calculus

Determine if the sequence is monotonic and bounded:

$a_n=\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}$

My guess is that $a_{n+1}\geq a_{n}$ so I'm going to try and show that  $a_{n+1}-a_{n} \geq0$

$a_{n+1}=\frac{(2(n+1)+3)!}{((n+1)+1)!}=\frac{(2n+5)!}{(n+2)!}$

$\frac{(2n+5)!}{(n+2)!}-\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

$\frac{(2n+5)(2n+4)(2n+3)!}{(n+2)(n+1)!}-\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

$\frac{(2n+5)2(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}-\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

$\frac{(4n+10)(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}-\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

$\frac{(4n+10)(2n+3)!-(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

$\frac{(2n+3)!(4n+10-1)}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

$\frac{(2n+3)!(4n+9)}{(n+1)!}\geq0$

Since $\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}$ is $a_{n}$ and since $n\in\mathbb{N}$,it follows that $\frac{(2n+3)!(4n+9)}{(n+1)!}\geq0$. Is my logic sound for this? Did I make any mistake?

Then for proving that it is bounded I will list out the first few terms and see if there is a pattern.

$a_{1}=60$

$a_{2}=840$

$a_{3}=15120$

These are just getting larger so there is no upper bound.

Furthermore, is it okay to say:

$a_n=\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(2n+3)(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!}$

Since $2(n+1)>(n+1)$, it follows that $2(n+1)!>(n+1)!$

So we have $(2n+3)\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!}>(2n+3)!$

And $(2n+3)!$ just keeps getting bigger as $n\rightarrow\infty$ so the sequence isn't bounded above

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be much faster, since:

$a_n=\dfrac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\Rightarrow a_{n+1}=\dfrac{(2n+5)!}{(n+2)!}$

Then

$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{(2n+5)!}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac{(2n+5)(2n+4)}{(n+2)}\cdot\dfrac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}=(4n+10)\cdot a_n>a_n,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is monotone increasing.

This sequence grows unbounded and it can be establishes easily.

By definition,
$$
a_n=\frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}
$$

Note that
$$
(2 n + 3) = (2 n + 2 + 1) = [2 (n + 1) + 1]
$$

Note that
$$
[2 (n + 1) + 1]! = [ 2 (n + 1) + 1] [2 (n + 1)] \cdots (n + 2) (n + 1)! 
$$

Hence,
$$
a_n = {[2 (n + 1) + 1]! \over (n + 1)!} = [2 (n + 1) + 1] [2 (n + 1)] \cdots (n + 2)
$$
which diverges to $+\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Hence, the given sequence $ \{ a_n \}$ is unbounded.